# How to use react to implement google Place's Searches, to create markers on the map?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-places-api, google-maps-react

Im new with react and i have created a react project. I would like to know how i can use this default starter project to implement the code from: 
[code link from google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search). The code is as the following, credit to google, linked above.

```
Css file- 

/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


HTML file-

<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>

Java script (pure js) file -

// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

var map;
var service;
var infowindow;

function initMap() {
  var sydney = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.867, 151.195);

  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  map = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById('map'), {center: sydney, zoom: 15});

  var request = {
    query: 'Museum of Contemporary Art Australia',
    fields: ['name', 'geometry'],
  };

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

  service.findPlaceFromQuery(request, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        createMarker(results[i]);
      }

      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    }
  });
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
}
```

I understand i need to create my key with google maps js and google places, however since Im new to react I'm unsure to how i could implement this into my new react project. Coudl some one show me how these files of code could be put together to be fit for a react project please. I apologies if i sound all over the place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to this [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/placesearch-hnvqnn?file=src/components/placeSearch.js) I made. Remember to change the value of "YOUR_API_KEY" so that the map will work properly.

Here is the App.js code snippet:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Map from './components/placeSearch';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      map: {}
    }
  } 

  handleMapLoad = (map) => {
    this.setState({
      map: map
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Map id="myMap" options={{center: { lat: 51.501904, lng: -0.115871 }, zoom: 13}}    onMapLoad = {this.handleMapLoad}/>  
      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The code for Place Search can be found in the Map components in placeSearch.js. Change the value of your API key here.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const map;
var markers = [];
var infowindow;
const API_KEY = "YOUR_API_KEY";
var place = [];


class Map extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }



    componentDidMount() {
            const script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=` + API_KEY + `&libraries=geometry,places`;
            script.id = 'googleMaps';
            script.async = true;
            script.defer = true;
            document.body.appendChild(script);
            script.addEventListener('load', e => {
                this.onScriptLoad()
            })

    }

    onScriptLoad() {
        map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(this.props.id), this.props.options);
        this.props.onMapLoad(map)

        var request = {
            query: 'Museum of Contemporary Art Australia',
            fields: ['name', 'geometry'],
        };

        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

        service.findPlaceFromQuery(request, function(results, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

                    var place = results[i];
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position:place.geometry.location,
                        title: place.formatted_address,
                    });
                    markers.push(marker);

                    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                    marker.addListener('click', () => {
                        infowindow.setContent(place.name);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
                }
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            }

        })
    }


    render() {
        return ( 
          <div id = "root" >
            <div className = "map" id = {this.props.id}/>
          </div>

        )
    }
}

export default Map;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and efforts for providing me the perfect solution to my question. Can’t thank you enough. 